# calling a completion handler Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

This may be a lot of work to retrieve a single value from firebase and get it so I can use it outside the closure but I can't seem to make anything simpler work...

While I may or may not have a decent handler created, so far it throws no errors until I try to call it with  and then I get: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(String) -> ()'

A: How do call the function? 
B: Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
var myName = ""

func getMyName(completion: @escaping (String) -> ()){
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
        databaseRef.child("bodhi").child((uid)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let bodhiDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            {
                let myName = (bodhiDict["Name"] as? String)!
                print ("myName in the closure: \(myName)")
                completion(myName)
            } else {
                completion("")
            }
        })
    }
}

getMyName(completion: (myName))
print ("myName Outside the closure: \(myName)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `getMyName` is incorrect. Change:

```
getMyName(completion: (myName))
print ("myName Outside the closure: \(myName)")
```

to either:

```
getMyName(completion: { (name) in
    print("Received \(name)")
})
```

or:

```
getMyName() { (name) in
    print("Received \(name)")
}
```

As you can see, the first `myName` variable you declared outside of the function is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, I got this to print, but it didn't change the variable outside the completion block.  So does that mean that all other functions that operate on this variable need to run inside it's completion block, or is there a way to mutate the variable when the page loads?

Comment: If your initial `myName` should be updated then add `myName = name` inside the `getMyName` block in my answer.

Comment: Yes!  It and delivered a beautiful notification with the name of the sender.  You made this whole frustrating weekend worthwhile.  This was the last missing link in about five different functions so I get to send the the app to beta in a a few days.  Once I had your answer and figured out the call, I removed the getMyName function from the post function and moved it to viewDidLoad and that let me do whatever I wanted with the variable after that.